# Passing dynamic CSS to jQuery.animate

Tags: jquery, animation

The documentation of [jQuery.animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) states that

> The only required parameter is a map
>   of CSS properties. This map is similar
>   to the one that can be sent to the
>   .css() method, except that the range
>   of properties is more restrictive.

So, why does this work

```
$('#con div').css( {
        top : function(i) {
            console.log(i);
            return (i * 500) + 'px';
        }
    }
);
```

and this doesn't?

```
$('#con div').animate( {
        top : function(i) {
            console.log(i);
            return (i * 500) + 'px';
        }
    }
);
```

The console shows that the function is being evaluated for css, but not for animate.  Am I missing something?

By the way, I'm using 1.4.2.

Comment: From reading the doc, it appears that the animate function is restrictive in the css map.  It allows only numeric values and some special exceptions.  I'm sure you read that too, but I wonder if that means it won't allow a function because it can't check the type.  Just speculating.  Might be time to look at the code because I can't find anything on this.

Comment: Agreed -- I just need to find another solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not be what you're after, but a simple solution would be simply to iterate over the elements and apply the animations individually:

```
$('#con div').each(function(i)
{
    $(this).animate({ top: i * 500 });
});
```

This is essentially what your snippet amounts to, after all.

Comment: Thanks, this works great!  I just started with jQuery.animate, and didn't think this would cause simultaneous animations.